# How to Show Image in Android using Java Code

Tags: android

I am try to show a image in android using java code not xml.
I have done it using xml file but my requirement is using 
java code to get more funcionality .

thanks in advance for help........

Comment: Can you post code and show us what you have and want to change/add?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309556/how-can-i-display-image-in-android-application/10309685#10309685

Answer (score 5):

IF you want to load image from drawable folder, you can using:

```
ImageView imgView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
Drawable  drawable  = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img);
imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use one default imageview in android xml when you are running app that time 
in activity you have to write this code so it will replace you image with another image.
Check following code

```
ImageView imgView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.default_imgView);
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimagename);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Drawable class you can show Image

```
Drawable  drawable  = Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath);
image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using **ImageView** to display the image in XML file with id **iv**.

In java file

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1); // image1 is image file available in drawables folder
```

Answer (score 0):

use ImageView  and learn more about it from here [imageview referecne](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

you can set image from bitmap,uri, from resources, etc...

Answer (score 0):

frist add the images to drawable folder 
  and using XML image view

```
 image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_1);
  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_2);
  ..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
 ImageView img = new ImageView(this);  /*In new version of Android Studio you don't need to do castling.*/
    img = findViewById(R.id.android_image);
    Drawable img_drawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.draw_img);
    img_cookie.setImageDrawable(img_drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked fine for me.

```
ImageView imageViewVar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
imageViewVar.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImgFile);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.