# How can I display image in Android Application

Tags: java, android, image, android-sdcard

I want to display Image in my Android application in specific size.
How can I do it? Please guide me?
And one more thing I want that image from SD card.
So please Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Sachin, first tell me. Where you want to display that image? Is it screen background?

Comment: on screen.may be in imageview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to create an imageview.

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
```

Create layout param to add imageview on layout

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Then get your image path

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/your folder name/image_name.bmp";
```

Set your image on ImageView

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Fetch your layout on which you want to add

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
```

Add your view to the layout

```
rl.addView(imageView, lp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code snippet to load image in imageview .

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageUri(Uri.parse("file://loaction"));
```

you can use the above sample method to display image in image from sd card.
Even dont hard code the file path use Environment.getExternalEnvironment() to get path.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder/filename.ext";
```

if no internal folder use below

```
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/filename.ext";
```

Comment: can you tell me path if I am getting image from folder name **AT** in SD card?

Comment: @SachinD Then, you should make a path like `/mnt/sdcard/AT/imagename.extension`

Comment: but its not working.It does not show image in `imageView`.It just showing me blank `imageView`.