# android :can't save image in folder and display it in activity

Tags: java, android, image, android-camera, android-camera-intent

i want to capture an image and save it in folder, but when i capture it, my image is not save in folder that i want, but just save in gallery, and the name of my image is not like what i want.
    my image also not display in my activity, is there anyone know, why this is happen?

this is my code :

```
    private void dialogKamera() {
String sdCard= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/android/data/spaj/spaj_foto.png";

                File file=new File(sdCard);

                if(file.exists())
                    file.delete();

                Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file); 

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
        }

            @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                image_spaj.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
```

i don't know where is my fault, i hope somebody can help me to solve my problem, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the output directory exists.

EDIT: removed spurious comment :-)

To ensure the directory exists:

```
File dir = file.getParentFile();
dir.mkdirs();
```

To display the image, here are several good resources:

[How can I display image in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309556/how-can-i-display-image-in-android-application),
[Displaying simple bitmap on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288550/displaying-simple-bitmap-on-android) has a list of other resources,
And the tutorial [Displaying Bitmaps in Your UI](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the directory exists, and then 
try this:

Change path to

```
String sdCard= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/spaj/spaj_foto.png"
```

**'Android'** instead of **'android'**.