# how to set image to image view by image name that stored in database in android?

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

i have a class that get two field(name and image) in database and set name to Text View and image set to image view
now i have problem with image , how to should set image to image view by image name that stored in database ?
Please Help me!

**my source code:**

---

```
public class ListMovie extends BaseAdapter {

    private Resources res = null;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflate;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ListMovie(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflate = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View v1 = view;

        if (v1 == null) {

            v1 = inflate.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txt_name = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

            holder.img = (ImageView) v1.findViewById(R.id.item_img);


            v1.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) v1.getTag();

        }
        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(arg0);


        holder.txt_name.setText(song.get("name"));

        return v1;

    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_name;
        ImageView img;  
    }
}
```

Comment: By 'image name' you mean the path to where the image file is stored?

Comment: no just store image name and put image to drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image in /res folder, you can use this in getView:

```
int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", 
   context.getPackageName());//initialize res and context in adapter's contructor
img.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Full code:

```
class ListMovie extends BaseAdapter {

    private Resources res = null;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflate;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ListMovie(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflate = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        res = a.getResources();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_img);
            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);
        holder.txt_name.setText(song.get("name"));
        int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(image_name, "drawable",
                activity.getPackageName());//initialize res and context in adapter's contructor
        img.setImageResource(resourceId);
        return view;

    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_name;
        ImageView img;
    }
}
```

change the `image_name` by your image's name

Comment: Error occurs with context.getPackageName() what should i do?

Comment: You have to create Context param then init in contructor. Or change context.getPackageName() by activity.getPackageName()

Comment: I did not notice, its possible explain it more?

Comment: i changed like this:
     int resourceId = res.getIdentifier("turkie", "drawable",MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME);
          holder.img.setImageResource(resourceId);

and in mainActivity

public static String PACKAGE_NAME;

PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

but still not working

Comment: I'm not usually use an activity instance in adapter. Instead I use a context because no need to use activity. And no need to created PACKAGE_NAME. Let's use activity.getPackageName(). What the error you've got?

Comment: ok, I'll do the same, now runtime error occurs , this error : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I guess that you are newbie so I've create a sample adapter for you http://pastebin.com/SSqeAQnQ

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library or [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) to dynamically load images.

**EDIT:**

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309556/how-can-i-display-image-in-android-application?lq=1). It has a pretty good example on how to load images through code.

Comment: no, just i want  show image in drawable to image view by name that stored in database